# drawing image from CALayers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I'm building some sort of censoring app. I've gotten so far that i can completele pixelate an image taken with my iPhone.

But I want to achieve in the end an image like this: http://images-mediawiki-sites.thefullwiki.org/11/4/8/8/8328511755287292.jpg

So my thought was to fully pixelate my image and then add a mask on top of it, to achieve the desired effect. So in terms of layers it goes like: originalImage + maskedPixelatedVersionOfImage.. I was thinking to animate the mask when touching the image, to scale the mask to the desired size. The longer you hold your finger on the image, the bigger the mask becomes...

After some searching, I guess this can be done using CALayers and CAAnimation. But how do I then composite those layers to an image that I can save in the photoalbum on the iphone?

Am I taking the right approach here?

EDIT:

Okay, I guess Ole's solution is the correct one, though I'm still not getting what I want: the code I use is:

```
    CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *mosaicLayer = [CALayer layer];

    // Mask image ends with 0.15 opacity on both sides. Set the background color of the layer
    // to the same value so the layer can extend the mask image.
    mosaicLayer.contents = (id)[img CGImage];
    mosaicLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    UIImage *maskImg = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mask" ofType:@"png"]];
    maskLayer.contents = (id)[maskImg CGImage];
    maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(100,150, maskImg.size.width, maskImg.size.height);

    mosaicLayer.mask = maskLayer;

    [imageView.layer addSublayer:mosaicLayer];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.layer.bounds.size);
    [imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *saver = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

So in my imageView i did: setImage, which has the original (unedited) version of the photo. On top of that i add a sublayer, mosaicLayer, which has a mask property: maskLayer. I thought by rendering the rootlayer of the imageView, everything would turn out ok. Is that not correct?

Also, I figured out something else: my mask is stretched and rotated, which i'm guessing has something to do with imageOrientation? I noticed by accidentally saving mosaicLayer to my library, which also explains the problem I had that the mask seemed to mask the wrong part of my image...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To render a layer tree, put all layers in a common container layer and call:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(containerLayer.bounds.size);
[containerLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: ok thanks, i'll try this. Do you think I'm having the right approach on the rest?

Comment: It might be worth noting that this approach would prevent you from doing the rendering on a background thread. If you need thread-safety, avoid `UI` functions and create your own `CGBitmapContext`: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html

Comment: This also may not be able to capture the image from an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, if he was using that to present the live camera frames.

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to drop support for pre-iPhone 3G S devices (iPhone and iPhone 3G), I'd suggest using OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders for this.  While it may be easy to overlay a CALayer containing a pixelated version of the image, I think you'll find the performance to be lacking.

In [my tests](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios), performing a simple CPU-based calculation on every pixel of a 480 x 320 image led to a framerate of about 4 FPS on an iPhone 4.  You might be able to sample only a fraction of these pixels to achieve the desired effect, but it still will be a slow operation to redraw a pixelated image to match the live video.

Instead, if you use an OpenGL ES 2.0 fragment shader to process the incoming live video image, you should be able to take in the raw camera image, apply this filter selectively over the desired area, and either display or save the resulting camera image.  This processing will take place almost entirely on the GPU, which I've found to do simple operations like this at 60 FPS on the iPhone 4.

While getting a fragment shader to work quite right can require a little setup, you might be able to use [this sample application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ColorTracking.zip) I wrote for processing camera input and doing color tracking to be a decent starting point.  You might also look at the touch gesture I use there, where I take the initial touch down point to be the location to center an effect around and then a subsequent drag distance to control the strength or radius of an effect.

Comment: interesting, i will certainly look at your code, especially at the touch gestures. But I'm trying ta shoot photos, no live video. The performance I get right now is sufficient. I thought about openGL but thought it was a little overkill for just one photo.. :) thanks anyway

Comment: @ThomasM - You still will need to have a live preview of some sort, even if you only care about images.  This could provide that kind of preview with realtime feedback, while making it very snappy to process the full-size image for saving when the user has composed their shot.

Comment: no really, the point is to take a picture and THEN censor it. So I really have no need for live action.. I looked at your project and it seems a little too complex for me at the time. I'm actually an AS3 developper and I'm taking my first steps in iOs dev. I'm finding the obj c a real pain, even for just trying to read it :) Nonetheless, I think I can use your project, or parts of it, for further learning and as a resource for some code. Seeing how things are done best is the best learning there is?

Comment: @ThomasM - Wouldn't a user still want a live preview?  Because they need to specify the position and size of the region to "censor", I can see a user quickly getting frustrated if they tap and drag to select a region with no visible feedback, only to find that when they took the photo it didn't turn out the way they wanted.  This is particularly true if the subjects of your photos are humans who won't sit still for many re-takes.  A live preview is a way of guaranteeing that things will turn out the how they want.

Comment: @ThomasM - As an additional learning resource, I taught a class on advanced iOS development this last year, for which the videos are available on iTunes U: http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=407243028 .  In particular, you might be interested in the camera, OpenGL ES 2.0, and Core Animation sections for what you're trying to do.